# Нужна помощь в подмене ссылки при помощи js без jquery

Tags: javascript, html, html5, http, https

Такая тема у меня есть определенная html страница и у меня есть код который ее создает. Надо сделать так при помощи js ,чтобы в теге, атрибуте href менялась ссылка, которую прописываю в js 
(нужны варианты как это можно сделать только при помощи js)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385207/how-to-change-href-attribute-using-javascript-after-opening-the-link-in-a-new-wi

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит. Тк айди ссылки не прописыватся. Уточнял же только при помощи js структура ссылки <a href="тут ссылка"></a> больше ничего нету

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("a[href='http://domain.com']"); -> вот так вот можно найти ссылку без id, определенную.